# Libreoffice Writer cannot open a file. "General error. General input/output error"

Tags: libreoffice

When I try to open a Libreoffice Writer file, this error appears: "General error. General input/output error". The file is stored in my local file system (in the Dropbox folder). File permissions are ok.

What should I do? I need to open it.

I searched in Google and tried some of what I read (for example, changing the file extension) but it did not work. I am confused.

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 and the version of Libreoffice is 4.0.4.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some extra information with the error? Like a path to a file

Comment: @TimothyPersoon: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, there is no extra information.

Comment: Where is the file stored? Local file system, remote? Are the file permissions ok?

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Thanks for your comment. The file is stored in my local file system (in the Dropbox folder). File permissions are ok.

Comment: Can you access other files in the folder or partition, and can you copy it to elsewhere and open it? Also, have you tried it in other programs, like [Calligara Words](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/calligrawords/) or [Abiword](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/abiword/) ? It should have an ODT extension, and be of the `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text` type ('Right Click' on it and then click 'Properties' to find that). Did you make the file?

Comment: @wilf: Thanks for your comment. Abiword opened it! Your answer is right. Could you turn your comment into an answer so that I am able to upvote it? May I know what happened to this file?

Comment: This happens also with later versions of LibreOffice (4.2.8.2, as a result of Calc crash, in my experience). The file was said to be irremediably corrupted by the crash even according to the auto-recovery tool. Though, after rebooting the system, the file was only said to be used by another user. There I could start off again from scratch. Consider rebooting the system and give LO one more chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening it with another Word processing application:

[[image] Abiword](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/abiword/)

[[image] Calligra Words](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/calligrawords/)